# In terms of performance, is it better for a database to be read optimized, or write optimized?

Tags: database, database-performance

The question is pretty damn self-explanatory. However, I would love to hear about some real life use cases and how that fits into that performance answer if possible.

By read optimized, I mean its faster to get back data using complex queries. For write optimized, obviously, it just means how fast we can store data.

Comment: Do you mostly read, mostly write, or equal combinations of both?

Comment: This  depends on whether reads are more important to you or writes

Comment: Alright. Assuming the average use case, I would say reads are more important (more frequent) than writes.